# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/myFile.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, kotlin, filenotfoundexception, android-contentresolver

Since Android Q came out there are some privacy changes in the permissions about read from external storage. I have a chat application that the user can choose a photo from Downloads etc... and send it. So i need to have access to that files. The way i did this is by using contentProvider.

```
context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { inputStream ->
    while (true) {
       numBytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)
       // .. do stuff
   }
}
```

The uri that is available at that time is -> **file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/myFile.pdf**

However i get a FileNotFoundException but the file trully exists.

I have set all the permissions in the manifest and granted them on the launch of the app. From Android <= 9 it works properly.
So what do i have to do...?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a chat application that the user can choose a photo from Downloads etc... and send it

That will not be possible on Android 10 and higher. You need to switch to something else. For example, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to allow the user to choose content from anywhere the user wants. Then, use the resulting `Uri` to upload it to your chat server, akin to how you are using the `Uri` in your code snippet. Or, better yet, don't read it all into memory — use something like [this OkHttp `InputStreamRequestBody` implementation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585#issuecomment-327319196).

For Android 10, you can add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your `<application>` element in the manifest. This opts you into the legacy storage model, and your existing external storage code will work. That will not work on Android R and higher, though, so this is only a short-term fix.

Comment: Well seems to me that the problem is that i have a file:// uri and not a content:// uri...

Comment: @james04: That definitely doesn't help. Your question does not indicate how you got that `Uri`.

Comment: I doesnt have to do where i got it from. The point is that the contentResolver has no reason to throw permission exception since its job is to get files from external sources...I will post again when i find the error

Comment: @james04: "I doesnt have to do where i got it from" -- yes, it does. You will need to stop using whatever you did that gave you that `Uri`, because that `Uri` is useless to you on Android 10 and higher. You will need to switch to using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` (or perhaps the older `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`).

Comment: Well if you try this in a Samsung S9 device you will see that it does not work.  Instead your intent should be something like intent = Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA")

Comment: @james04: "Well if you try this in a Samsung S9 device you will see that it does not work" -- `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` works just fine on a Samsung Galaxy S9. "Instead your intent should be something like intent = Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA")" -- relying on an undocumented and unsupported `Intent` action is not a wise move. For example, it might give you a `file` `Uri` that you cannot use on Android 10 and higher.

Comment: Well...i think you are right. ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT works fine :/
And it returns a content uri so the initial code that i had works also fine!